# Does Bitcoin Core install well in PureOS following this tutorial?

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, bitcoin-core-accounts, bitcoincore-gui

I would like to install Bitcoin Core in PureOS distro. I was going to follow this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmMVoBgIzNc

Will this work or do I need to take additional steps, like installing some dependencies or stuff that PureOS is missing by default? What exactly?

I saw that Jameson Lopp uses PureOS for his node on a blog post so it's at least possible to use but not sure if I will encounter problems. Also I want to use the GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PureOS is a GNU/Linux distribution based on Debian.

If looking to build from source:

Ubuntu and Debian specific instructions mentioned in this doc should help you in using Bitcoin Core on PureOS: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#ubuntu--debian

You can also follow basic steps mentioned by Jonatack if doc is confusing: https://jonatack.github.io/articles/how-to-compile-bitcoin-core-and-run-the-tests

Else if want to use the binaries:

1. Download tar.gz file from https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/
2. Extract
3. Go to 'bin' directory and run bitcoind or bitcoin-qt